# Node Red Gauge not displaying values?

Tags: node-red

Struggling to get gauge working (node-red dashboard).

I have a node-red function which returns temperature in degrees C, the ouput of this function has 2 connections, one to a debug node which shows the ouput is msg.payload:number (and the temperature i.e. 21.3, 19.6 etc) and the other connects to a gauge node.

Irrespective of what I put in 'Value Format' for the gauge
(i.e. {{msg.payload}} or {{msg.payload:number}} or {{value}} or {{value | number:1}}C )
the gauge is always 'grey' and shows no value despite the debug output fromn the previous function showing the temperature changing every 2 secs.

Do I have to convert the numerical value to a string or something before sending to gauge, or group some nodes together or is some other magical process required (the gauge should update when the input does).

I thought you could just send numerical values to gauge and it would display something.

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I needed to define an array in the function, otherwise nothing comes out of any secondary output.

There were many issues after that including with dashboard sliders (which can't be queried for information unless thay are 'moved') which put an end to that project.

Thanks for everybody's response.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be an error in function nodes. If you have 2 outputs, the second output does not output anything, only the first.

Comment: Edit the question to show an example of your function node trying to output to multiple outputs. The Array format is important. If you want the same message to go to both the debug node and the gauge there is no need to 2 outputs, just wire both to the first output.

Comment: Firstly your initial post didn't make clear that your function node has two outputs, you said it has two "connections". Usually this would mean two wires connected from a single output. If your debug node had indeed been connected to the same output of the function node as the gauge, then there would be a problem. But it was connected to a different output. Secondly, the whole point of setting multiple outputs from a function node is to send multiple *different* messages. The documentation is very clear. Thirdly it seems strange you assumed the function node "has an error".